# Is it "to be relieved of a burden" or "relieved from a burden"?

Tags: prepositions

Is it correct to say "I am relieved from a burden" or is it "I am relieved of a burden"?

Answer (score 1):

I am relieved **of** a burden.

> Meaning of relieve *somebody* of *something* in English
>
> — phrasal verb with relieve verb
>
> (TAKE)   C2 formal
>
> to take from a person something that they are carrying, in a helpful
> or polite way:
>
> *May I relieve you of that heavy bag?*

[Relieve sb of sth (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/relieve-sb-of-sth)